# Importing from one module to another

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I have two modules in the same directory:
`PDSC2.py` and `db_layer.py`
I want to import a class named `DBLayer` from `db_layer.py` so I write:

```
from db_layer.py import DBLayer
```

But I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db_layer'
```

Does somebdy have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `.py` file extension from the `import` statement: `from db_layer import DBLayer`

Comment: Yea just do what @jdehesa says

Comment: Just did, same error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

first of all assume that this python files in the same directory and then remove extension from your code.

```
from db_layer import DBLayer
```

**or:**

```
from db_layer import *
```

Comment: do you have all python files in the same dir?

Comment: maybe you don't have any class or function named DBLayer in db_layer.py

Comment: It autocompletes DBLayer, as I type

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory in a place where python searches for modules, python path? Do you have a `__init__.py` in the directory (it can be blank)?

Comment: This looks like it is a comment as opposed to an answer.  Any questions or comments about the post are more appropriately placed under the post by clicking the "add a comment" link.

Comment: @Zyhael Yes, I changed PYTHONPATH to include the modules and I do have an __init__.py file in the directory. It still has the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste the program file `db_layer.py` in the `\Python\Python36-32\Scripts` directory 
, then use `from db_layer import DBLayer` or `from db_layer.py import DBLayer` to call the desired class in the python program .

Actually sometimes changing the directory of the called module  to `\Python\Python36-32\Scripts` solves these types of problems easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\carmel.han\\AppData\\Roaming\\QGIS\\QGIS3\\profiles\\default\\python\\plugins/filterparcel")
from db_layer import DBLayer
```